# Angular2: what is the best way to manifest using library on angular-cli.json?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

thanks in advance.

I'm developing angular2 application, of course using angular-cli.json.

but somehow, I found that manifesting styles(.css files) and scripts(.js files) on that has serious problem.

for example, when I used to write css on .html files in plain way, I was able to write tag like below.

```
<link href="fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css" media="print"/>
```

but, you know, if you only depend on angular-cli.json, there's no way to specify **media="print"** on there.

I still don't want to write [link] and [script] tags on html directly, only want to use angular-cli.json as much as possible.

Is it possible? Can't it help writing [link] tags on html directly to solve this problem?

any advice please.

Comment: Since Angular-CLI doesn't provide a way to specify the `media` in the styles array, you're pretty much going to have to manually link the print stylesheet.